# wordpress blog hosted with openshift security issue

Tags: openshift

I have hosted my wordpress blog with openshift. I have a custom domain yourtechchick.com which is mapped to Cname your-techchick.rhcloud.com .
I am using the basic plan and can not upload custom SSL certificate.

How do I redirect https to http so that user never actually has to see security risk or no security certificate risk?

I tried editing .htaccess to redirect http to https but it gives too many redirects or redirect loop in that case.

How do I fix this?

Comment: If the user’s browser refuses to even connect to `https://www.yourtechchick.com/` because of the invalid certificate, then you can not redirect at all – because the request does not even get to that stage.

Comment: User's browsers probably won't refuse to connect. Websites do run just fine without ssl certificates. Just that it asks for permission and I need it to be automatically redirected from https to http in case url has https

Comment: Why exactly has it been downvoted? What's wrong with this question?

Comment: _“Websites do run just fine without ssl certificates”_ – not if the request is made using HTTPS. In the best case, the browser asks the user if they want to accept an invalid certificate – but that doesn’t always have to be the case, the browser might simply block the request. Browsers do not chose to make the request an HTTPS one by themselves – so I don’t see how this problem actually occurs in the first place … if you don’t _have_ proper SSL, then don’t link to your page using HTTPS anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. Answers my question .Wanted to know if it was just me doing something wrong .

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit your wp-config.php file. You can edit it from the wp dashboard or through ftp.

Find the line that says:

> define( 'force_SSL', true );

Change "true" to "false" and save it.
This will disable HTTPS.